# How to debug my appengine/php/wordpress site returning truncated html content?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

My site is hosted on WordPress on Google AppEngine. Although it's been working fine for months together and there has been no new deployment or content change for months, since Feb 22, 2015, it goes into a state after which it returns only a blank home page or any other page for every request afterwards.

On debugging, I found that it's due to receiving a truncated HTML - the content size (before gzip encoding) is only 7K instead of the regular 33K. If I restart the appengine instance, it begins to work fine for a few hours until it goes again into that state. I toggled memcache, pagespeed, etc but nothing helps. I haven't upgraded my app to the php 5.5 runtime from Google. My assets are all stored in Google Cloud Storage. The truncation happens just in the middle of the following div, like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a id="top" href="http://www.sadhusangaretreat.com" title="sadhu-sanga.appspot.com"
```

Any ideas how I can debug this further?

Comment: I've removed the link to the site itself, as that makes it too localised, and won't help other readers with the same problem once the issue is fixed. Put everything evidencing the problem in the question itself please. FWIW, it sounds like an out of memory error. What is your PHP process size? Anything in your PHP logs?

Comment: Thanks halfer. Since it's on appengine I don't have access to the PHP stats. The closest data I could find is that the instance is currently at 52 MB memory utilization. halfer, if it's OOM, would you expect all subsequent requests to get truncated exactly at the same point consistently ?

Comment: That would be a possible outcome, yes. What do your logs say? (I don't know what you mean about "stats" but you will absolutely have access to the error log).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11695) bug. WordPress eats the error messages which is why you're not seeing anything in the logs.

The fix is rolling out to production now. If you app is still not working feel free to ping me the app_id and I will take a look into it.